# mysql inserting variable from jython

Tags: python, mysql, jython

I am trying to insert a variable into mysql from jython and am getting weird errors

```
var1='abc' 
cursor.execute (""" INSERT INTO Master (Name) VALUES (%s) """, (var1))
```

I get an error `zxJDBC.ProgrammingError: optional second argument must be a list or tuple`

I am just trying to add one variable into a table called Master and column named 'Name' so I figure I am smart and I'll change var1 to `var1=['abc']`

and I get `zxJDBC.Error: error setting index [1] [SQLCode: 0]
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). [SQLCode: 0], [SQLState: S1009]`

I have tried to do var1[0] when inserting and still nothing.   I have tried other ways such as ending my insert statement with ..VALUES (%s) """, % var1) but that doesn't work either..

Sorry to bug you, as I suspect this will be extremely easy.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I am looking at documentation on python because I can't find much on jython mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change (var1) to (var1,).  Parenthesis group unless you add a comma, which then indicates a tuple.

Also, check the parameter style, as it may not be recognizing the %s format.  Per PEP 249:

```
paramstyle

String constant stating the type of parameter marker
formatting expected by the interface. Possible values are:

'qmark'         Question mark style, 
                e.g. '...WHERE name=?'
'numeric'       Numeric, positional style, 
                e.g. '...WHERE name=:1'
'named'         Named style, 
                e.g. '...WHERE name=:name'
'format'        ANSI C printf format codes, 
                e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'
'pyformat'      Python extended format codes, 
                e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Steve.  I tried cursor.execute (""" INSERT INTO Master (Name) VALUES (%s) """, (var1,))
and still got the same error.  I tried to change var1 to var1='abc' and var1=['abc'] and both gave me the error: zxJDBC.Error: error setting index [1] [SQLCode: 0]
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). [SQLCode: 0], [SQLState: S1009]

Comment: D'oh!  I got my edit in after you wrote your reply.  My guess is that it's not recognizing the %s parameter style, which would explain why it says there are 0 parameters.  Try changing the '%s' to '?' in your query and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Howard.  It worked like a charm.  I didn't know the symbols had to be different.  Thanks so much! Have a great day!